# How implement Default Exception Handler with Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have a GlobalExceptionhandler :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(FooException.class)
    public ModelAndView alreadyVerifiedExceptionHandler(FooException ex) {
        ModelAndView response = new ModelAndView();
        response.addObject("status", ex.getStatus());
        response.addObject("errorCode", ex.getErrorCode());
        response.addObject("errorMessage", ex.getErrorMessage());
        return response;
    }
    .....
}
```

I have several ExceptionHandler and I would have a ExceptionHandler by default. How to do?

spring version : 3.2.3

[Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.2-webmvc-exception-handler-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but it catches all exceptions that do not have ExceptionHandler.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(Exception ex) {
...
}
```